# Navbar hamburger menu fix color property on side menu

Tags: css

When I resize my window and open my hamburger side menu the red menu item color is not spread over the whole menu item as you can see in the navbar. I am not a CSS expert so I decided to ask this question over here.

Here is a screenshot to clarify where I am talking about if you didn't understand.

Screenshot: https://gyazo.com/06691a8d7fca1ec8fbc9a5c5594cd596

[image]

How it has to be: https://gyazo.com/4f84faa183513f16a2eac647cdc75e25

[image]

Here is my source code:

```js
 $(document).ready(main);

var contador = 1;

function main(){
 $('.menu_bar').click(function(){
  // $('nav').toggle(); 

  if(contador == 1){
   $('nav').animate({
    left: '0'
   });
   contador = 0;
  } else {
   contador = 1;
   $('nav').animate({
    left: '-100%'
   });
  }

 });

};
```

```css
/*------Nav-------*/
header {
 width:100%;
}
 
header nav {
 width:100%;
 background:#2f354e;
  z-index:11;
}
 
.menu_bar {
 display:none;
}
 
header nav ul {
 overflow:hidden;
 list-style:none;
 margin: 0px;
 padding: 0px;
}
 
header nav ul li {
 float:left;
}
 
header nav ul li a {
 color:#fff;
 padding:14px;
 display:block;
 text-decoration:none;
}
 
header nav ul li span {
 margin-right:10px;
}
 
header nav ul li a:hover {
 background:red;
 text-decoration: none;
 color:#ffffff;
}

 
@media screen and (max-width:800px ) {
 header nav {
  width:150px;
  height:100%;
  left:-100%;
  margin:0px;
  position: fixed;
 }
 
 header nav ul li {
  display:block;
  float:left !important
 }
 
 .menu_bar {
  display:block;
  width:100%;
  background:#ccc;
    text-align:center;
 }
 
 .menu_bar .bt-menu {
  display:block;
  padding:20px;
  background:#2f354e;
  color:#fff;
  text-decoration:none;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size:25px;
  -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
  box-sizing:border-box;
 }
 
 .menu_bar span {
  float:right;
  font-size:30px;
 }
}
/*--------End of the nav-------*/

/*-------- Generic styles-------*/
body{
  overflow: scroll;
  margin:0px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<head>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
 
</head>
<header>
    <div class="menu_bar">
        <a href="#" class="bt-menu"><span class="fa fa-bars"></span>Fastmovie Renesse</a>
    </div>

    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="index.php"><span class="fa fa-home"></span>Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="movies.php"><span class="fa fa-film"></span>Films</a></li>
            <li><a href="reserveringen.php"><span class="fa fa-envelope"></span>Reserveren</a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><span class="fa fa-info-circle"></span>Over ons</a></li>
            <li style="float:right"><a href="login.php"><span class="fa fa-sign-in"></span>Login</a></li>



        </ul>
    </nav>
</header>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Set `width: 150px;` to  `header nav ul li a:hover` in `@media screen and (max-width:800px ) {}`** 
Here is JSFiddle:https://jsfiddle.net/k1cbfh70/1/

```js
 $(document).ready(main);

var contador = 1;

function main(){
 $('.menu_bar').click(function(){
  // $('nav').toggle(); 

  if(contador == 1){
   $('nav').animate({
    left: '0'
   });
   contador = 0;
  } else {
   contador = 1;
   $('nav').animate({
    left: '-100%'
   });
  }

 });

};
```

```css
/*------Nav-------*/
header {
 width:100%;
}
 
header nav {
 width:100%;
 background:#2f354e;
  z-index:11;
}
 
.menu_bar {
 display:none;
}
 
header nav ul {
 overflow:hidden;
 list-style:none;
 margin: 0px;
 padding: 0px;
}
 
header nav ul li {
 float:left;
}
 
header nav ul li a {
 color:#fff;
 padding:14px;
 display:block;
 text-decoration:none;
}
 
header nav ul li span {
 margin-right:10px;
}
 
header nav ul li a:hover {
 background:red;
 text-decoration: none;
 color:#ffffff;
   width: 150px;
}

 
@media screen and (max-width:800px ) {
 header nav {
  width:150px;
  height:100%;
  left:-100%;
  margin:0px;
  position: fixed;
 }
 
 header nav ul li {
  display:block;
  float:left !important
 }
     header nav ul li a:hover {
       width: 150px;
    }
 .menu_bar {
  display:block;
  width:100%;
  background:#ccc;
    text-align:center;
 }
 
 .menu_bar .bt-menu {
  display:block;
  padding:20px;
  background:#2f354e;
  color:#fff;
  text-decoration:none;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size:25px;
  -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
  box-sizing:border-box;
 }
 
 .menu_bar span {
  float:right;
  font-size:30px;
 }
}
/*--------End of the nav-------*/

/*-------- Generic styles-------*/
body{
  overflow: scroll;
  margin:0px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<head>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
 
</head>
<header>
    <div class="menu_bar">
        <a href="#" class="bt-menu"><span class="fa fa-bars"></span>Fastmovie Renesse</a>
    </div>

    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="index.php"><span class="fa fa-home"></span>Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="movies.php"><span class="fa fa-film"></span>Films</a></li>
            <li><a href="reserveringen.php"><span class="fa fa-envelope"></span>Reserveren</a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><span class="fa fa-info-circle"></span>Over ons</a></li>
            <li style="float:right"><a href="login.php"><span class="fa fa-sign-in"></span>Login</a></li>



        </ul>
    </nav>
</header>
```

Comment: tell me for more help

Comment: Thx for fixing it but right now If I move my mouse on a item its tripping xD

Comment: tell me if it helps

Answer (score 0):

```
header nav ul li {
   display:block;
   float:left !important
}
```

This simply needs to be `float:none` instead, so that the items go over the full width, instead of shrinking to what their content demands only. (And no need for the `!important`, at least not within the example you have given.)

Comment: The login item moved to the left if i'll changed it

Comment: Well then format that separately … for example by putting a class on it to begin with, or by using `:last-child`, or …

Answer (score 0):

Just put the `width:100%` on li tag in smaller resolution.

Example: put width:100% on this part of your css code.

```
 @media screen and (max-width: 800px)
header nav ul li {
    display: block;
    float: left !important;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Here is jsfidle link of your code working [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/ckgjeym5/)

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me, add the `width: 100%;` in your **media query**

```
@media screen and (max-width: 800px)

    header nav ul li {
    display: block;
    float: left !important;
    width: 100%;

   }
```